# Error: string[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains' - works and doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Working on an MVC5 app. I'm a little confused by this one.... I have 2 variables, both defined as string arrays (msUsers and msSites). One, msUsers, allows me to use "Contains", the other doesn't. Here's a snippet of the code....

```
    private IQueryable<Event> GetEventsFiltered(
        string userName,
        string workStatus,
        string[] msUsers,
        string[] msSites,
        int? eventTypeId)
    {
        IQueryable<Event> events = this.db.Events;

        if (msUsers != null)
        {
            events = events.Include(a => a.AspNetUser)
                .Where(a => msUsers.Contains(a.AspNetUser.Id));
        }

        if (msSites != null)
        {
            // It doesn't like Contains here....
            events = events.Include(a => a.Branch)
                .Where(a => msSites.Contains(a.Branch.Id));
        }
```

The error (for the last "Contains")...

```
 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method 
  overload 'Queryable.Contains<int>(IQueryable<int>, int)' requires a receiver of type 
  'IQueryable<int>'
```

I'm a little confused because the first usage of Contains works fine against the SAME type of variable. Any suggestions/ideas? Thanks!

***** UPDATED to add NAMESPACES ******

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

using AuditingApp.Models;
using AuditingApp.Services;
using AuditingApp.ViewModels;

using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

Comment: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Please include the list of the namespaces you are using. Issues like this are classically that System.Linq is missing as a namespace or a namespace related to extensions is missing.

Comment: why is `msSites` a `string[]` when its values are of type `int`?  Can you just add `toString` to `a.Branch.Id`?

Comment: @L.B If that were it, then wouldn't he be getting the error for both `msUsers.Contains()` and `msSites.Contains()`?

Comment: It looks like Branch.Id may be an integer instead of a string where AspNetUser is a string. Can you confirm?

Comment: @stephen.vakil I think you might be onto something Subtle, but important. Why is msBranches an array of int but msUsers an array of strings? Looks like they are declared the same.

Comment: @L.B I updated my original post with the namespaces.

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 it would be better for us to see what types `AspNetUser.Id` and `Branch.Id` are

Comment: I am saying that your table column is an int so you are trying to compare  a string to an int without doing proper type conversion.  It would seem like your parameter should be `int[]` not `string[]` or, if not, you need to convert the int to a string for `Contains` to work

Comment: @stephen.vakil can you create a new reply so that I can award you. That was the key!!! Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is indicating a type mismatch, basically.  Your database column for `Branch.id` is an integer, and your `msSites[]` is a string array.  You are trying to use `Contains` to compare a `string` to an `int` without doing type conversion.

**Option 1**
Since the id appears to always be an int, you can refactor your method to accept `int[] msSites` and that would likely resolve the problem.

**Option 2**
If you can't change the argument types to your method, you could try converting `a.Branch.Id` to a string in the `Contains` call.